# Exercise on Dominated Convergence Theorem (verification)

Tags: integration, measure-theory, solution-verification, lebesgue-integral

> Evaluate $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_0^1
>  \frac{n^{(3/2)}x}{1+n^2x^2} \,\mathrm{d}x \,.$$

Solution:
Let $$f_n(x) = \frac{n^{(3/2)}x}{1+n^2x^2} \,.$$ It is clear that $f_n \rightarrow 0$ regardless of $x$ as $n$ grows large, and thus that $f_n$ converges to zero pointwise.

Now we have
$$\frac{n^{(3/2)}x}{1+n^2x^2} = \sqrt{n}\frac{nx}{1+n^2x^2} \,. $$
Let $t = nx$, so that the above expression becomes
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\sqrt{t}\frac{t}{1+t^2} \,,$$
and define $$h(t) = \frac{t^{3/2}}{1+t^2} \,.$$
Since $h(0) = 0$ and $h(t) \rightarrow 0$ as $t \rightarrow  \infty $, and $h(t)$ has no other possible sources of discontinuity, it follows that $h(t)$ is bounded. It thus follows that
$$\frac{n^{(3/2)}x}{1+n^2x^2} \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\times M$$
for some real positive constant $M$. Now since $1 / \sqrt{x} \in \mathscr{L}^1$ on $[0,1]$, we have the sequence is bounded above by an $\mathscr{L}^1$ function, and the dominated convergence theorem applies. It follows that the original integral tends to zero.

Comment: You want to replace $L^2$ by $L^1$ because this is what you need. Also note that $1/\sqrt{x} \not\in L^2$. Apart from that, the proof is correct. Also replace "is zero" in the end with "tends to zero".

Comment: Yes, of course. I was stuck in L^2 for some reason. Thank you!

Comment: Actually your $h$ is a $h_n$ so it still depends on $n$ although you haven't noted it! You you $M$ is also still an $M_n$. But what you need is that your $h_n$ are bounded uniformly and you haven't shown this.

Comment: @Gono Hmmm, you are correct. This is not clear. My thinking was that if $t=nx$ (keeping in mind that $x\in (0,1) $ and we can show that $h$ is bounded for all $t$, then that would translate into $h$ being bounded for all $n$. Is this false, or at least not necessarily true?

Comment: @Gono $h$ doesn't depend of $n$.

Comment: @Chris Your thoughts are right, just be aware that this is not instantly clear. Actually it holds $$\{h(nx) | n\in\Bbb N, x\in (0,1)\} \subseteq \{h(t) | t\in\Bbb R\}$$ and this is the reason why your argument holds if you show the right set is bounded, so is the left one.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: your integral is given by $$\frac{\log \left(n^2+1\right)}{2 \sqrt{n}}$$
Can you compute the limit?
the searched limit is $0$

Comment: Alright, I will look into this. Is my proof wrong though, or are you just suggesting an alternative approach to it?

Comment: i think that $h(t)$ is bounded can be proven by calculus